# Is there any way to add Interfaces with endpoint using groovy in soapui?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to add the test cases at run time, for which need to add the interfaces with endpoint in SOAPUI first then create a testsuite/testcases.

Is there any way to do the same using Groovy script?
NOTE: Don't have wsdl or wadl file.

Comment: If you do not have wsdl, then how are you going to add interface? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have few new APIs, which i want to add to SOAPUI using groovy.Currently I had added the APIs to the Project manually in the tool. I want that new APIs(endpoints/headers..) to be added to some file and groovy pick those and do the needful.

Comment: Not to discourage. Adding the services (wsdl or wadl or swagger definition) is one time job. Why do you want to invest your efforts?

Comment: Any ways, see if this helps - https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/ed7398271673b57a89935e1fba98c813b387de56/groovy/UpdateWSDLDefinition.groovy